# Fetching entity's relationship NSSet

Tags: core-data, request, nspredicate, fetch

I want to fetch all the entities which are in relationship to a specific entity (one to many-relationship). What is the exact NSPredicate I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself, anybody who has the same Problem:

`NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY entityName=%@", @"B", selected];`